# iOS app review - Video streaming MPEG-DASH for longer than 10 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

we would like to use MPEG-DASH within iOS to play streaming video.
However, according to review notes - [Review notes](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#media-content) - there is stated, that the app is prohibited to use another tech. than HTTP Live stream within video content longer than 10 minutes. Does anyone have any experience with kind of topic?

Because I found an app approved with this technology.[iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/expressplayer/id658596028?mt=8)

So if we submit the app with MPEG-DASH, are we prohibited to use streams longer than 10 minutes?

Comment: You will never be able to tell whether or not you app will be rejected. Just because some other app has passed review does not mean that your app will

Comment: How would you play videos using MPEG-DASH? I couldn't find any open source player on internet which supports dash format for iOS.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't answer such a question. But we are able to play the MPEG-DASH ;-)

Comment: Any hints? ;) Was performance good enough for adaptive streaming? We used vlc player, and the performance sucked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found an answer with coop of this service: 
[Express Play](http://www.expressplay.com). It is really easy to use and you can even try demo if you want.

It is very promising, because basically you can use advantages of DASH and locally you get HLS. So you do not need any special own player, you can use standard MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: So is it legal to play MPEG-DASH longer than 10 min on App Store apps or not?

Comment: apple did not adjust their guidelines regarding the usage of streaming video. so: no :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the latest regarding iOS and MPEG-DASH in this article which was posted last week.  I had hoped to use MPEG-DASH myself for a project but had to opt for HLS, at least for my first iteration, due to lack luster iOS support.

[Tell me more...](http://www.streamingmediaglobal.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/The-State-of-MPEG-DASH-Deployment-96144.aspx)

Comment: Did you find any promising way to play dash videos in iOS devices?

Comment: Players for iOS that support MPEG-DASH are still very few in number. I, personally, have had good experience with [Viblast Player](http://viblast.com/player). It's cheap and easy to use. There is sample [project in github](https://github.com/Viblast/ios-player-sdk) to get you started.